# Emailing a comment to an email address stored in a table

Tags: php, mysql

In a comment system, I am using variables called `$comment` and `$submittor`.  I am using a MySQL table called "login" that contains fields called "username" and "email."

The field "email" is an email address.

I would like to send an email with `$comment` in it to the "email" where "username" = "$submittor."

Here is what I have so far:

```
$queryem = sprintf('SELECT email FROM login WHERE username = $submittor');
```

How can I send the email?

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: In PHP you can use double quotes to do variable interpolation.

Comment: sprintf('SELECT email FROM login WHERE username = $submittor')

and

"SELECT email FROM login WHERE username = $submittor"

are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Better use PHPMailer library - it comes with freat tutorial based on GMail SMTP server:

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=exampleagmail

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP's [`mail`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function:

`mail($email, 'New comment!', $comment);`

[(More on emailing with PHP)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mail.php)